# Pentaho Web services Lookup can't load my wsdl

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I want use pentaho Spoon to access to a webservice du to Web service Lookup.
When I load the wsdl from the url I've got an error :

```
Could not find the schema with the name {link to schema}SearchActorsRequest within the specified wsdl.
```

But when I search for SearchActorsRequest in wsdl I find it. I don't understand why Pentaho don't.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried loading and verifying the wsdl in another application (something like SoapUI)? It could be that the urls in the wsdl are not accessible.

Comment: @Cyrus yes I try the webservice at first in SoapUi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the webservice I can't answer your question directly. In my experience the Web Services lookup step only supports very basic scenarios and I don't even bother trying it anymore.

The alternative way to do it in PDI is detailed in one of the sample transformations included in the installation:
**General - Annotated SOAP Web Service call - dialog.ktr**

Starting from that example, you paste your SoapUI generated request XML into the Javascript step and insert the input fields at the question marks. The endpoint and any custom headers can be defined separately and then configured in the HTTP lookup step.

Comment: It's for work, the webservice is localy stock, I can't give you access. For the exemple, I see it before, I'm trying to use it but I get an eroor 500 in response >﹏<

Comment: I wasn't asking for access, just making clear that I can't help figure out the error without a lot more details. The most likely issue is that in the wsdl there are some include statements for additional schema documents that the Webservices step is not following, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway

Comment: Ok I din't remove the encoding of the exemple first. Now It work. @Cyrus